# VBS Path Error Handling

Tags: vbscript

I have been running into a problem for the past few months with this VBScript not working 100% on every computer. It seems to be some Windows 10 and Windows 7 Ultimate that have the problem.

I have been using a workaround of a different VBScript with the change of instead of `\DATA` its just `DATA`. I have been trying to use error handling to just ignore the problem and run the other version of the code, but even with `On Error Resume Next` or `Try Catch Finally` statements, I still get the popup of cannot find the file.
I have also tried `On Error GoTo` error handling.

How do I make it try a path variation and not kick back any error msg then move to the next path option?

```
Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim WshShell, InPath
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

InPath = WshShell.CurrentDirectory + "\DATA"
'shell.ShellExecute "application", "arguments", "path", "verb", window
shell.ShellExecute "Install.bat", , InPath, "runas", 1
Set shell = Nothing
```

Comment: Please show the actual error message. Also, what is the value of `WshShell.CurrentDirectory` (both on systems where the code is working and systems where it's not working).

Comment: Error msg was: Install.bat cannot be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another work around probably....

Check for the path, if not exists go with other path. Look into comments.

```
Dim fso, InPath
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Get the path
InPath=WshShell.CurrentDirectory +"\DATA" 
exists = fso.FolderExists(InPath)

'Check if not exists, replace with other path
If Not(exists) Then 
   InPath=WshShell.CurrentDirectory +"DATA"
```